# How can I set a reason and a duration for a suspension in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I have a working suspension command but cannot have the bot repeat the reason and the duration, then delete the trigger. I also have no idea how to make the bot automatically unrole after the suspension duration. Here's my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_any_role('✪ Commissioner ✪', '✪ Vice Commissioner ✪', '✪ Board of Directors ✪')
async def suspend(ctx, *, member:discord.Member):
 guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
 role_name = 'Suspended'
 role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Suspended')
 embed = discord.Embed(
 colour = discord.Colour.red())
 [
   embed.add_field(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> **Success!**', value=f'{member.mention} has been successfully suspended.')]
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is by using the asyncio module. You could replace your current code to:

```
import asyncio

@bot.command(pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_any_role('✪ Commissioner ✪', '✪ Vice Commissioner ✪', '✪ Board of Directors ✪')
async def suspend(ctx, time, *, member:discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
    role_name = 'Suspended'
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Suspended')
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
    [
      embed.add_field(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> **Success!**', value=f'{member.mention} has been successfully suspended.')]

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(role)

    # Using asyncio module to wait
    await asycio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

And you would use the command like: `[prefix]suspend({time}, {member})`

--EDIT--

I noticed that you didn't define `role` variable. You could do that like:

`role = ctx.guild.get_role(roleID)`

So now, your command should look like:

```
@bot.command(pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_any_role('✪ Commissioner ✪', '✪ Vice Commissioner ✪', '✪ Board of Directors ✪')
async def suspend(ctx, time, *, member:discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
    role_name = 'Suspended'
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Suspended')
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
    [
      embed.add_field(name='<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> **Success!**', value=f'{member.mention} has been successfully suspended.')]
    
    # Defile the "role" variable
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(roleID)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(role)

    # Using asyncio module to wait
    await asycio.sleep(time)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```